# selenium in python, how to ignore errors without closing the browser

Tags: python, selenium

I'm doing an automation using Selenium in Python

How could I simply ignore an error that happens on the site without it closing the browser?

I looked in several places about and I didn't find anything that helped me

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
# Needed libs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Then, if something fails, your browser will not be closed.